# Zod promise rejection: ZodError always returns empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, zod

I want to validate data that comes from the backend, I want this data to resemble this typescript shape

```
export interface Booking {
  locationId: string;
  bookingId: number;
  spotId: string;
  from: string;
  to: string;
  status: "pending" | "confirmed" | "closed";
}
```

so I have written zod schema and a validator function like so:

```
const bookingOnLoadResponse = z.array(
  z.object({
    locationId: z.string(),
    bookingId: z.number(),
    spotId: z.string(),
    status: z.literal("pending" || "confirmed" || "closed"),
    from: z.string(),
    to: z.string(),
  })
);

export function bookingOnLoadValidator(bookingArray: unknown) {
  return bookingOnLoadResponse.parse(bookingArray);
}
```

now I know that the problem is with the status field, as it was added recently and I see in the logs that this field is missing in the response, but from Zod all I get is:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: ZodError: []
at http://10.3.42.237:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:226607:293 in _createSuperInternal
at node_modules/zod/lib/ZodError.js:29:8 in constructor
at node_modules/zod/lib/types.js:29:22 in handleResult
at node_modules/zod/lib/types.js:120:23 in ZodType#parse
at utils/zodSchemas/bookingResponseSchema.ts:16:9 in bookingOnLoadValidator
at utils/fetchFunctions.ts:28:9 in fetchBookings
```

is there a way to get a more detailed description of what causes the problem?
Thanks

Comment: The zod schema and validator code looks fine. Can you share some more code about how you are getting response from the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the promise rejection is a result of `parse` throwing. If it's called from within a promise's callback or from an `async` function then the ultimate result would be a promise rejection.

`parse` is going to throw if it fails to parse the schema you've specified. If anything about the shape of your data is different than you're expecting, then it will throw. It's hard to say exactly why it's throwing without seeing the `JSON`, but my guess is that your definition for `status` is not correct.

`||` is going to be evaluated as a logical or expression so `"pending" || "confirmed" || "closed"` resolves to `"pending"` (because "pending" is truth-y and `||` will resolve to the first value in the chain that is truth-y). Because of that, the other values for status are going to result in failure to parse.

Try

```
status: z.enum(["pending", "confirmed", "closed"]),
```